# Mutex is rabbitmq

Tags: queue, rabbitmq

Is that possible to have mutex in RabbitMQ queue, i.e. If a client is reading from the queue, no other client should read from the queue. is that possible?

Let me explain my scenario:

> Two application running in two different servers. reading the same queue. But, if one application is running and reading the messages from the Queue, the other application should not do anything. if the Main application fails or stopped, then the other application should
>   start reading from this queue.

This is kind of a fail over mechanism. Have anyone tried this before. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: your approach is kinda flawed. You should handle this at application level not at the queue level.

Comment: I thought it will be interesting if there is a way in rabbitmq, so posted it here, to see any RabbitMq expert may answer this, which may help others and me in some point. Thanks for your input @Darth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as i have searched, no solutions found...A simple solution is

> - create a queue call it as Lock Queue.
> - Have only one message make the application to read it from the queue.
> - When ever the application starts in a another server, it will wait for the message in the Queue. so, if the first one fails second
> - one will read the message and start processing the message in desired  queue from which it should read.

A Mutex in Queue, that's it. 
Note: This approach will work only if there is only message in the lock queue. make sure you handle it in your application.

Answer (score 1):

This talk explicitly explains why this is a bad idea:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XiXZOF6dZuE&feature=share&t=29m55s

from ~ 29m 55s in

Comment: When you're going to link to something other than another StackOverflow question, please include enough information in your answer that it would still be useful if the link breaks in the future.